# Facebook - How to keep variables from app_data after login redirect?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

With much thanks to other threads here I'm able to get variables passed to a facebook app tab page (With PHP sdk ) as such if the user is already logged in to facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/my_dull_page/156000037732522?sk=app_305100762893495&app_data=choice%3Dmy_dull_choice

```
//check if logged in
// if not -> login -> redirect
```

$data=  $facebook->getSignedRequest();
   $app_data = $data['app_data'];

However if the user wasn't logged in, the variables are lost after the redirect, what would be the best way to pass them over?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the php session.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['variable'] = $value;
```

Then on the page after you redirect, you could check for the existence of the variable and set it, then destroy it.

```
session_start();
if( isset( $_SESSION['variable'] ) )
{
    $var = $_SESSION['variable'];
    unset( $_SESSION['variable'] );
}
```

The second way, and I am not sure how you are redirecting, is to pass the variables as GET vars in the redirect..

```
http://domain.com/redirect.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3
```

Then read the variables on the redirected page...

```
$var1 = isset( $_GET['var1'] ) ? $_GET['var1'] : NULL;
```

Comment: ( sorry I'm having trouble figuring how to line break in this comment..)                                                         Thanks for the quick & straightforward response!  I'm redirecting back to the app tab page after login (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/pages/my_dull_page/156000037732522?sk=app_305100762893495&app_data=choice%3Dmy_dull_choice) ,                                        So I did session_start, and then $_SESSION['choice'] = $choice;  On the other end after login, I could verify that the $_SESSION['choice'] is indeed set,  and is not set if the user was already logged in.

Comment: however the value comes out to be null/blank, does it have to do with the redirect back to app tab?  Or do I have to add something like session_set_cookie_params (0,"/", ".mydomain.com"); ?   Thanks again! @pogeybait

Comment: On the page you redirect to, make sure to start the session with session_start(); Any page that you need to access the $_SESSION variable must have a session_start(); That is the only thing I can think of that would be causing an issue. Unless you did something during your PHP setup to change the way sessions are stored, the session should be writing to your temporary directory by default. On Mac/Linux the temp directory is /tmp. Not sure what it is on Windows. That directory must be writable as well. Might look into that.

Comment: Got it working now, thank you! Will vote up when I have enough repute.